# How to check for a non existing value in a map typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the below map in typescript:

myMap = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 4, "d" => 5}

The values can be 1 , 2 , 3, 4, or 5 only.

I need to check for the values in the myMap from 1 to 5 and if any of the value is missing, i want to log it and exit the loop.
Eg: In the above map, value 3 is missing. So, i would want to log that value.

Can anyone let me know, how this could be achieved in typescript ?

Comment: looks like you just have an object and that needs to be checked for values. Are you talking about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into consideration that values are `1 to 5`, you could change array as well and use some other values with specific range and use it with `map` with this -

```js
var map = new Map();
map.set('a', 1)
map.set('b', 2)
map.set('c',4) 
map.set('d', 5)

var arr = [];

for(var singleVal of map.values()) arr.push(singleVal)
    
var originalArr =  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // taking into consideration that you have some original array like this, where '3' is present

for(var i=0; i<originalArr.length; i++)
    if(!arr.includes(originalArr[i]))
    {
        console.log(originalArr[i]);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of the [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) in `Map`. Then `filter` the numbers array and check if the set [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) each number

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      map = new Map([ ["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 4] ]),
      set = new Set(map.values()),
      missing = numbers.filter(n => !set.has(n))

console.log(missing)
```

Answer (score 0):

That something more javascript specific then typescript.

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("a", 1);
myMap.set("b", 2);

let hasThree = [...myMap.values()].includes(3);

console.log(hasThree);
```

You can use `.values()` and spread it into an array and use then `.includes`

[image]

Here is an image that shows all methods of the Map prototype.

Comment: How is this checking for the missing value in the map ? It is just running through the existing values. @Ifaruki